# Magento Credit Memos Model

Tags: magento

Can anyone help with the model/collection to search through all credit memos within magento as opposed to orders?
I can use Mage::getModel('sales/order') for orders but not seeing for credit memos

Kind regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I put this together quickly. For example, let's say you wanted to grab the comments, you can do something like this.

**Get CreditMemo Comment Based on Order**

```
$incrementId = 100000002;
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_creditmemo_collection')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('increment_id', $incrementId);

foreach($collection as $item) {
    $creditMessage = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_creditmemo_comment_collection')
                   ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $item->getEntityId());

    foreach($creditMessage as $message) {
            echo $message->getComment();
    }
}
```

You can filter the collection with the `increment_id` or even the `order_id` :)

**Get All Comments**

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_creditmemo_comment_collection');
```

Below is a list of tables for creditmemo

```
sales_flat_creditmemo
sales_flat_creditmemo_comment
sales_flat_creditmemo_grid
sales_flat_creditmemo_item
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think it would be better to access the collection via `Mage::getModel('sales/order_creditmemo_comment')->getCollection()` - you shouldn't need to access the resource model directly

Answer (score 0):

**right way to get Credit Memo comment collection**

```
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_creditmemo_collection')
            ->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $order->getId()); /* here we have no load memo by order id not increment id.Increment id is the creditmemo increment id not order increment id. */

foreach($collection as $item) {

    $creditMessage = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_creditmemo_comment_collection')
                   ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $item->getId()); /* here we need to use parent_id not entity_id.*/

                   }
                   var_dump($creditMessage->getData());
                   exit();
```